# Rules for constructing a sequence (induction)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What steps are required to built a sequence? Here is an example:

Show that there is a sequence of rational numbers that converge to pi.

Note that $0 < \pi$. Since the rationals are dense in the reals, we know that there exists $q_1 \in (0, \pi)$. Moreover, we can choose $q_2 \in (\pi - \pi/2, \pi)$. In general, we can find a $q_n \in (\pi - \pi/n, \pi)$.

Thus we have two sequences $\{\pi - \pi/n\}$ and $\{q_n\}$ such that $\forall n \geq 1$, we have $\pi - \pi/n \leq q_n \leq pi$ which the squeeze theorem says $q_n \to \pi$.

---

Why can we say "In general" for the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence? What does this actually mean?

Do we techically need to use induction?

Like, assume the inductive hypothesis, $\pi - \pi/n \leq q_n \leq \pi$. Then, $\pi - \pi/n \leq \pi - \pi/(n+1) \leq \pi$. By the density of reals, there exists $q_{n+1}$ such that $\pi - \pi/(n+1) \leq q_{n+1} \leq \pi$. By induction, the sequences exist.

Do we simply ignore this step because it is simple?

Comment: You don't use your "induction hypothesis" in your induction step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need induction here to construct the sequence: For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a rational number $q_n\in [\pi-\pi/n,\pi]$, so you can choose it to be the $n$-th number of your sequence.